# How to say "As a <position>, ..."

Tags: grammar

Example : **As a friend**, I think we should...

What do you add to ともだち to add the "As a" prefix?

Also, after that part, does the rest of the sentence follow the normal rules of a Japanese sentence?

What I mean is, could I comfortably add "As a friend" at the start of any Japanese sentence without changing anything for it to make sense?

Edit : Also, if you could put your answers in both Kanji and kana, that would be great, since I do not understand Kanji yet. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, ～として is used for "as a". You use a noun before として. For example:

> As a friend...
>   友{とも}だちとして...

Comment: So if it was "As your friend, I think you should eat", would the translation be ともだちとして、あなたはたべましょうとおもいます?

Comment: I would say 「ともだちとして、あなたがたべたらいいとおもいます。」But it may not be the best option.

Comment: Why is that so? I'm sorry for the many questions. I'm a beginner in Japanese.

Comment: I interpreted your "should eat" as an advice, hence used "たべたらいい". "たべましょう" is more a proposition on the part of speaker, something likes "let's eat".

Comment: Moreover you won't use the masu form before to omoimasu. You could say tabeyou to omoimasu, however as Szymon said, it will reflect *your* intentions.

Comment: Also, I'd go with "友達として言うけど、食べたほうがいいよ"。